# How do I install python3-gi within virtualenv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I'm following the [Python GTK+ 3 Tutorial](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html) and I'm trying to get a working install running in virtualenv. I have [python3-gi](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python3-gi) installed through the Ubuntu package manager already. Things look like this:

```
:~$ mkvirtualenv py3 --python=/usr/bin/python3
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in py3/bin/python3
Also creating executable in py3/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...python
done.
(py3):~$ python
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'gi'
>>> 
(py3):~$ deactivate
:~$ /usr/bin/python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gi
>>>
```

As you can see, python3-gi is obviously not available within virtualenv but I am not sure how to install it since python3-gi is installed through my package manager and not with pip.

Comment: When creating the virtual environment add the flag `--system-site-packages`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It is now possible to resolve this using [vext](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vext). Vext allows you to install packages in a virtualenv that individually access your system packages. To access `gi`, do the following:

```
pip install vext
pip install vext.gi
```

Comment: after doing this, I still get `no module named gi`

Comment: @bluppfisk: you still have to `sudo apt install python-gi`. As I understood, `vext` only gives _visibility_ to the `gi` system libraries

Comment: This is incorrect. On Ubuntu 18, in a Python3.7 virtualenv, I still get `ImportError: No module named gi`.

Answer (score 18):

**Update 2023 – macOS**

1. Install GTK+ 3 and Gobject Introspection with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

   ```
    brew install gtk+3 gobject-introspection
   ```
2. Create a virtual environment.

   ```
    python3 -mvenv venv
   ```
3. Install `pygobject` in the virtual environment (`pycairo` should come as a dependency).

   ```
    venv/bin/pip install pygobject
   ```

Tested on macOs Ventura 13.5, Python 3.11, Apple M1 Max chip.

**Update 2018 – Debian Stretch**

1. Install GTK+ 3 / GIR.

   ```
    apt install libcairo2-dev libgirepository1.0-dev gir1.2-gtk-3.0
   ```
2. Create a virtual environment.

   ```
    python3 -mvenv venv
   ```
3. Install `pygobject` (`pycairo` should come as a dependency).

   ```
    venv/bin/pip install pygobject
   ```

**Update 2018 – macOS**

1. Install GTK+ 3 and Gobject Introspection with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

   ```
    brew install gtk+3 gobject-introspection
   ```
2. Create a virtual environment.

   ```
    python3 -mvenv venv
   ```
3. Install `pygobject` in the virtual environment (`pycairo` should come as a dependency).

   ```
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" venv/bin/pip install pygobject
   ```

**Original answer**

This is what I did to get GTK+ 3 within a Python 3.5 virtual environment on OS X 10.11.

1. Install GTK+ 3 with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

   ```
    brew install gtk+3
   ```
2. Create and activate a virtual environment.

   ```
    pyvenv-3.5 venv
    source venv/bin/activate
    cd venv
   ```
3. Install [pycairo](http://cairographics.org/pycairo/) on the virtual environment.

   ```
    export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/pkgconfig

    curl -L https://cairographics.org/releases/pycairo-1.10.0.tar.bz2 | tar xj
    cd pycairo-1.10.0
    export ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64'

    python waf configure --prefix=$VIRTUAL_ENV # It's ok, this will fail.
    sed -i '' '154s/data={}/return/' .waf3-1.6.4-*/waflib/Build.py # Bugfix: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=76759
    python waf configure --prefix=$VIRTUAL_ENV # Now it should configure.
    python waf build
    python waf install

    unset ARCHFLAGS
    cd ..
   ```
4. Install [pygobject](http://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/PyGObject) on the virtual environment.

   ```
    export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig

    curl -L http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/pygobject/3.12/pygobject-3.12.2.tar.xz | tar xJ
    cd pygobject-3.12.2

    ./configure CFLAGS="-I$VIRTUAL_ENV/include" --prefix=$VIRTUAL_ENV
    make
    make install

    cd ..
   ```
5. Profit.

   ```
    Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  5 2015, 21:12:44)
    [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, Pango, GObject
    >>> from cairo import ImageSurface, Context, FORMAT_ARGB32
    >>>
   ```

Python 3.5 downloaded and installed from [PSF](http://www.python.org/).

Comment: Thanks for this Rafa, going to try this today actually.

Comment: Just tried this Rafa and this worked very well for me, one typo I saw. sed -i '' '154s/data={}/return/' .waf3-1.6.4-*/waflib/Build.py should be sed -i '154s/data={}/return/' .waf3-1.6.4-*/waflib/Build.py

Everything else worked out perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Hey Malcom, that is not a typo. The `-i` option with an empty string tells the standard `sed` that comes with OS X to perform an inline replace on the file without creating a backup. Maybe you are using the GNU implementation of `sed` instead?

Comment: Shucks, that's exactly it, I have gnu sed installed ! Thanks again for this !!

Answer (score 13):

I haven't found a proper solution to this. When I run into situations where I can't get something to install into a virtualenv directly, I symlink it there and it works fine (there are probably exceptions, but this is not one of them).

```
ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi /path_to_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/
```

Not elegant in the slightest; seems nicer than giving the virtualenv full access to all system packages though (via `--system-site-packages`).

Comment: `ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from 'gi'`

Answer (score 6):

The pip package name is somewhat counterintuitive - use `pip install PyGObject`.

Answer (score 1):

I installed [`pgi`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pgi/0.0.10.1) via `pip`, which may be an option. It is apparently API compatible with `PyGObject` and so far seems to work ok running `Gtk`.

Comment: From the GitHub About: "Unmaintained: Use PyGObject instead" https://github.com/pygobject/pgi

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu (tested in 19.04), you can download the package and then install it as follows:

```
apt-get -y download python3-gi
dpkg-deb -x <package>.deb <virtualenv path>
```

In Ubuntu, the name of the downloaded package is `python3-gi_3.32.0-1_amd64.deb`.

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo apt install build-dep python3-gi
pip install PyGObject
```